# GROUP BY not working in left join query

Tags: sql, join

I m trying to use group by clause in left join sql query and it is not working.
Please help me out, thanks in advance.

```
SELECT Cust_Mst_Det.Cust_Hd_Code,
       Cust_Mst_Det.First_Name,
       SL_HEAD20152016.vouch_date AS invoice_2,
       SL_HEAD20142015.vouch_date AS invoice_1,
       Cust_Mst_Hd.EMail
FROM Cust_Mst_Det
LEFT JOIN SL_HEAD20142015 ON Cust_Mst_Det.Cust_Hd_Code=SL_HEAD20142015.Member_Code
LEFT JOIN SL_HEAD20152016 ON Cust_Mst_Det.Cust_Hd_Code=SL_HEAD20152016.Member_Code
LEFT JOIN Cust_Mst_Hd ON Cust_Mst_Det.Cust_Hd_Code=Cust_Mst_Hd.Cust_Hd_Code
WHERE cust_mst_det.first_name!='NIL'
GROUP BY Cust_Mst_Det.Cust_Hd_Code
ORDER BY SL_HEAD20152016.vouch_date DESC,
         SL_HEAD20142015.vouch_date
```

Comment: "... and it is not working" --> Please write a better explanation! What is not working? Do you get an error? Do you get unexpected results? What results do you get? What results do you expect? AND: What RDBMS do you use?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that it is impossible to use an ORDER BY on a GROUP BY summarisation. My fundamental logic is flawed. I will need to run the following subquery.

ex :

```
SELECT p.*, pp.price 
FROM products p 
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT price FROM product_price ORDER BY date_updated DESC ) pp 
ON p.product_id = pp.product_id GROUP BY p.product_id;
```

This will take a performance hit but as it is the same subquery for each row it shouldn't be too bad.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which DBMS you are using, but on an Oracle your query will not work at all.

- First issue: The GROUP BY statement is used in conjunction with the aggregate functions to group the result-set by one or more columns. You do not have any aggregating function in your SELECT statement (count, max, etc.)
- Second issue: you must specify all columns from SELECT statement in your GROUP BY statement (excluding columns that represents results of aggregation).

As I said I don't know which DB is used by you, but those two points should be applicable for the most of SQL standards.